# How do i Remove a tab or space from a Read Line Using Regular Expression

Tags: c#

i am creating a Log Parser whereby i Load a log file and Parse it by going through the log file one line at a time. I am using Regular Expression to parse my Files for a specific Pattern. The problem i am having is that in the actual log file there is a tab or space before or in front of the selected line and my data will not match my comparison data.

How do i remove the Tab or white space in front of the line. I tried Trim() and trimStart() that did not work. Here is my sample codes:

Log File Sample pattern:
[ANY__MOD,80,*AUDIT_GROUPS*] [ANY__MOD] audit_groups_category Key1 contains invalid value. Replace dictionary dat file with one having valid Key1 value ANY_MOD.

Regex Pattern i have for this:
string Pattern = @"/.*[([.\d\s\w*]*),([.\d\s\w*]*),([.\d\s\w*]*)]\s*[([.\d\s\w*]*)]\s*(.)*";

Problem i am having:"**\t**[.22.12.,81,*AUDIT_GROUPS*] [.22.12.] audit_groups_category Key1 contains invalid value. Replace dictionary dat file with one having valid Key1 value ANY_MOD.

```
 [.22.12.,81,*AUDIT_GROUPS*] [.22.12.] audit_groups_category Key1 contains invalid value. Replace dictionary dat file with one having valid Key1 value ANY_MOD.
```

My Sample Code:

```
private void ValidateUsingRegularExpression(string Pattern,  string serviceName)
       {
           System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Launch();

           string line;
           int counter = 0;
           string ServiceName = Helpers.GetServiceName(serviceName, _integrationType);
           string serviceLogPath = Helpers.GetTppInstallDir() + "logs\\" + ServiceName + ".txt";
         //  string serviceLogPath = @"C:\totalpayment\logs\EngineService.txt";
         // If file does not exist
            if(!File.Exists(serviceLogPath))
           {
            throw new ApplicationException("Was unable to find Log file " + serviceLogPath );
           }

          System.IO.StreamReader file = new System.IO.StreamReader(serviceLogPath);

           line = file.ReadLine();

           while (line != null)
           {
               line = file.ReadLine();
               if (line == null)
               {
                   return;
               }
               line = line.Trim();

                   if (Regex.IsMatch(line, Pattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase))
                   {
                       line = line.Trim();
                       line = line.TrimStart();
                       if (ErrorToValidate == line)
                       {
                           _ValidateErrorinLogFile = "Found";
                           counter = counter + 1;
                          // counter++;
                           _TotalLinesFound = counter.ToString();
                       }

                   }
           }
       }
```

main function that calls

```
public void  ValidateCompareExclusionErrorsInLogFile()
       {

          // string Pattern = @"\[\d+\,[A-Z_]+\]
          // string Pattern = @"\[([\w\*]+),(\d+),([\w\*]+)\]\s*\[([\w\*_]+)\]\s*([\w\\d\s\.]*)";
           //string Pattern = \[([\w\*]+),(\d+),([\w\*]+)\]\s*\[([\w\*\_]+)\]\s*([\w\\d\s\.]*);

           string Pattern = @"/.*\[([.\d\s\w\*]*),([.\d\s\w\*]*),([.\d\s\\w\*]*)\]\s*\[([.\d\s\w\*]*)\]\s*(.)*";

           //ValidateUsingRegularExpression(Pattern, "TPP.EngineService");
           ValidateUsingRegularExpression(Pattern, "engine");
           ValidateUsingString(ErrorToValidate, "engine");
           //These options are here when needed,  If you need to setup different suite of test to run same scenario on different engine, 
           //this can be dynamically done by turning on the following options below. 
            //  ValidateUsingString("field","engine");

       }
```

Comment: I don't have the answer for you but `Trim()` will remove whitespace including tabs from the start and end of your string. So double check the logic surrounding this. Also, how do you know it is a tab at the start, could it be another character?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works with the data you provided:

```
^\s+\[[^]]+]\s*\[[^]]+\].+$
```

And this is what that means:

```
^ (anchor to start of string)
Any whitespace character 
+ (one or more times)
[
Any character not in "]"
+ (one or more times)
]
Any whitespace character 
* (zero or more times)
[
Any character not in "]"
+ (one or more times)
]
. (any character)
+ (one or more times)
$ (anchor to end of string)
```

Comment: Thank you for your FeedBack, However i am still having this issue with the Tab or white space in the code even after i did what you suggested. Thank you again for your Feedback

Comment: Thank you very much this works very well and my problem is Solved. Thank you so much for assisting me on this.

Comment: @user1097970 - np. Glad I could help.